# method not found in java @ jboss4.0 and linux environment

Tags: java, linux, jboss

In Linux Method not found in jar file

Environment 1: [Working fine with  JBoss 4.0 & Windows ]
Environment 2: [Issue in with  JBoss 4.0 & **Linux**]

ERROR MESSAGE:

> SEVERE: >> {==================STACK TRACE IS==========================
>   Sep 4, 2012 5:12:13 PM com.bct.platform.logger.BPMSLogger logString
>   SEVERE: >> com.bpms.core.exception.BPMSRuntimeException: BEACP015: No
>   method available like
>   this->uploadDocument(org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem,java.lang.String,java.lang.String)com.bpms.engine.workflowprocessor.actions.ActionCallProgram.executeAction(ActionCallProgram.java:571)
>   com.bpms.engine.CommonInterface.executeActions(CommonInterface.java:188)

we are call this reflection

Below is the code sample ,Am trying to call the saveALDocument when cant find the Java in Linux environment . In windows its working fine

```
    import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.activation.MimetypesFileTypeMap;

import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem;
import org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils;
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;

public class FileUpdation
{

    public String saveALDocument(FileItem filebuff,String fileName,String fileUuid) throws Exception
    {

        String uuidURLMap = "Retry...";
        System.out.println("***************SaveDOCUment Entered *************");
        try {

            byte[] content = filebuff.get();
            String filename = filebuff.getName();
            if (filename != null) {
                filename = FilenameUtils.getName(filename);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return uuidURLMap; 
    }

    public String _getDocURL(String uuid)
    {
        String strUrl = null;
        try {
            .........
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return strUrl;
    }

    public String _getName(String strUUID) {

        return fileName;
    }
}
```

Comment: Same issue coming....U mean that apache jar?

Comment: commons-fileupload-1.2.jar and commons-io-1.1.jar , put them in lib

Comment: Thank you for your timely support... Issue solved .I had problem in  Method call ....

Comment: just added that as answer accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

commons-fileupload-1.2.jar and commons-io-1.1.jar , put them in lib